# how to install Blackberrry JDE plugin 1.3 on Eclipse 3.5

Tags: blackberry-eclipse-plugin

please can someone tell me how to install BB JDE plugin 1.3.0 on Eclipse 3.5?.i have tried by going to Help>Install new software but it's not working.When i was at Install new software dialog,i clicked on the Add and a window came up asking me to type-in the local name and the location of the software,i'd already unzipped the file in a folder in my C:\ drive.When i clicked 'Ok' after everything,i got a message telling me that it couldnt locate the repository file.I directly installed the plugin and am confused on how to go about this again.pls someone who uses Eclipse 3.5 and has successfully installed this plugin should help me here becuase this is really geetting on my nerves and i dont think i would want to use Netbeans IDE because it dosent have a 3rd party plugin installation